# Customizing a Retrofit request

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm trying to make a POST request using Retrofit2 for my Android app, to an endpoint that has these characteristics:

> ### Authentication
>
> Required before any action can be performed, as it returns the necessary keys and tokens used for further requests.
>
> - Endpoint: `https://api.example.com/v1`.
> - Type: `POST`.
> - Parameters:
>
>   - `level`: Fixed value, always set to `1`.
> - Body fields:
>
>   - `user`: The username to authenticate.
>   - `pass`: The associated password.
>   - `new_pass` *(optional)*:  Change the account password to this value upon successful login.
>   - `api_key`:
>     API key.

This endpoint is used to authenticate an user (optionally changing its password afterwards) but it requires an API key to be present - this key is baked in the application, it is not user-defined.

Basically, a login request would look like this:

```bash
curl --request POST 'https://api.example.com/v1?level=1' \
--form 'user="my_username"' \
--form 'pass="my_password"' \
# --form 'new_pass="my_new_password"' \
--form 'api_key="abc"'
```

Now, a Retrofit request can be customized when defining it, but I gut stuck after reaching this point, because I cannot configure the request the way I want (mandatory, optional and fixed-value payload):

```kotlin
private const val API_KEY = "abc"

interface ExampleApiService {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("?level=1")
    fun login(
        @Field("user") username: String,
        @Field("pass") password: String,
    )
}
```

As I understood it, I can pass a single `@FieldMap params: Map<String, String>` as a parameter when defining the login function, and simply add in that whatever I need, when I need:

```kotlin
interface ExampleApiService {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("?level=1")
    fun login(@FieldMap params: Map<String, String>)
}
```

But this means leaving it up the the calling code to pass the necessary parameters, which I find it to be quite inelegant.

I know I can overload the `login` function to handle several cases, or I can have multiple "login type" function, but if there are multiple optional parameters they will add up pretty fast.

Another option would be to wrap my code and have that wrapper do the proper calculations, but I would like to avoid another middleman.

What I'm looking to achieve is along these lines - I want to use annotations to define the API:

```kotlin
interface ExampleApiService {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("?level=1")
    @Field("api_key", API_KEY)
    fun login(
        @Field("user") username: String,
        @Field("pass") password: String,
        @Field("new_pass") newPassword: String? = null,
    )
}
```

Is this possible to do with Retrofit? Can I use a `RequestBody` to achieve this result?

An example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can achieve this using multiple ways. By using

```
 data class ApiRequest<T>(
    @Field("api_key") val apiKey: String = API_KEY,
    val data: T
 )
        
data class LoginRequest(
   @Query("level") level: Int,
   @Field("user") val username: String,
   @Field("pass") val password: String,
   @Field("new_pass") val newPassword: String? = null
)

interface ExampleApiService {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/v1")
    fun login(apiRequest: ApiRequest<LoginRequest>)

    companion object {
        fun create(): ExampleApiService {
            return retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(retrofit2.converter.moshi.MoshiConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
                .create(ExampleApiService::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

Or Using intercept to add code that should always exist.

```
class ApiKeyInterceptor : Interceptor {
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val originalRequest = chain.request()

        // Create a new FormBody.Builder
        val formBodyBuilder = FormBody.Builder()

        // Add api_key as a field
        formBodyBuilder.add("api_key", API_KEY)

        val originalBody = originalRequest.body()
        if (originalBody is FormBody) {
            for (i in 0 until originalBody.size()) {
                formBodyBuilder.add(originalBody.name(i), originalBody.value(i))
            }
        }

        // Build the new FormBody
        val newFormBody = formBodyBuilder.build()
        val modifiedRequest = originalRequest.newBuilder()
            .method(originalRequest.method(), newFormBody)
            .build()

        return chain.proceed(modifiedRequest)
    }
}
```

I would however, recommend to add API Key as part of headers in that way intercept will be like

```
class ApiKeyInterceptor : Interceptor {
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val originalRequest = chain.request()
        val modifiedRequest = originalRequest.newBuilder()
            .addHeader("api_key", API_KEY)
            .build()
        return chain.proceed(modifiedRequest)
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, neither option does what I was looking for, as intercept requires doing something outside the API definition, and the other suggestion amounts to using a single function definition with mandatory/optional parameters, and relying on the calling code to provide the correct values. However, this has shown me that what I was looking for is not feasible, so you have my upvote.